# Search in Json file and get results using Javascript

Tags: javascript, json

I'm developing an dictionary app for FirefoxOS by Javascript . my json file look like this

```
[
{"id":"3784","word":"Ajar","type":"adv.","descr":" Slightly turned or opened; as, the door was standing ajar.","track":"a","track_2":"Aj","track_3":"Aja"},
{"id":"3785","word":"Ajar","type":"adv.","descr":" In a state of discord; out of harmony; as, he is ajar with the world.","track":"a","track_2":"Aj","track_3":"Aja"},{"id":"3786","word":"Ajog","type":"adv.","descr":" On the jog.","track":"a","track_2":"Aj","track_3":"Ajo"},
{"id":"3787","word":"Ajutage","type":"n.","descr":" A tube through which water is discharged; an efflux tube; as, the ajutage of a fountain.","track":"a","track_2":"Aj","track_3":"Aju"}                               ]
```

Now I want to query this json file where word = "aj" and get the all the matched results or id's of the matched results . How can I do that ?

Comment: With ECMAScript 6 or without? With ES6 it’s `yourArray.filter(a=>a.word.match(/aj/i));` or `yourArray.filter(a=>a.word.match(/aj/i)).map(a=>a.id);`.

Comment: I have no idea whether firefoxOS supports ECMAScript or not . but I mainly need a solution using JavaScript . :/

Comment: Well, JavaScript _is_ ECMAScript (plus the browser stuff). The problem is, not every browser or system fully supports ES6. ES5, however, is supported largely by all browsers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TRY THIS
[UPDATED FIDDLE DEMO](http://fiddle.jshell.net/v4vishnuprasad/jue9kb7t/2/)

```
var jsonArrr =[
{"id":"3784","word":"Ajar","type":"adv.","descr":" Slightly turned or opened; as, the door was standing ajar.","track":"a","track_2":"Aj","track_3":"Aja"},
{"id":"3785","word":"Ajar","type":"adv.","descr":" In a state of discord; out of harmony; as, he is ajar with the world.","track":"a","track_2":"Aj","track_3":"Aja"},{"id":"3786","word":"Ajog","type":"adv.","descr":" On the jog.","track":"a","track_2":"Aj","track_3":"Ajo"},
{"id":"3787","word":"Ajutage","type":"n.","descr":" A tube through which water is discharged; an efflux tube; as, the ajutage of a fountain.","track":"a","track_2":"Aj","track_3":"Aju"}                               ];

var matchMe = new RegExp('^' + 'aj', 'i');
    var matches = [];
        for (var i in jsonArrr) {
            if (jsonArrr[i].word.search(matchMe) > -1 ) {

                    matches.push( {'id': i, 'word': jsonArrr[i].word} );

            }
        }
```

To see the result

```
 for (var i in matches) { 
                console.log(matches[i].word);
                //your code
                }
```

Take **console window** in **Inspect Element** to see the result

Comment: Now If i want to search using word = 'aj' and `track_3` = 'aja' what should i do?

Answer (score 0):

```
var matchedIndexes = []
for (var i=0; i < array.length; i++) {
    var obj = array[i];
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty("word")) {
        if(obj["word"].match(/aj/i)) {
            console.log("matched");
            matchedIndexes.push(i);     
        }
    }
}
```

`matchedIndexes` will contain all indexes in which object has word "aj" (**case insensitive**). `array` in this code is your object of arrays.

Answer (score 0):

Loop through the json array :

```
var result = null;
    Objects.forEach(function(obj, i){
        if(obj.word == 'aj'){
            return result = obj;
        }
    });
    console.log(result);
```